# Saving multiple selection dropdown into 1 column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-select

I want to save multiple drop down selection into one column in the database.

I have the following :

```
<select name="pack_choice[]" style="width:270px; margin-bottom:2px;">
<option value=''>---Select---</option>
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_package_source where pack_type = 'Bronze' AND pack_desc = 'Pasta/Noodles/Vegetables'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$pack_id = $row['pack_code'];
echo "<option value='".$row['pack_code']."'>".$row['pack_part']."</option>";
} ?>
</select>
<select name="pack_choice[]" style="width:270px; margin-bottom:2px;">
<option value=''>---Select---</option>
<?php 
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_package_source where pack_type = 'Bronze' AND pack_desc = 'Seafoods'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
$pack_id = $row['pack_code'];
echo "<option value='".$row['pack_code']."'>".$row['pack_part']."</option>";
}
?>
</select><br/>
```

and here is my query

```
$pack_choice = implode(", ",$_POST['pack_choice']);
$qry = "Insert INTO tbl_packages (pack_choice) VALUES ('{$pack_choice}')";
$result_set = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: I know it is not your question, but maybe storing 2 values in one column is not the best solution. Because when retrieving the data out of the database you have to split the values again (and assume none are missing and in the correct order).

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close quote:

```
$qry = "Insert INTO tbl_packages (pack_choice) VALUES ('{$pack_choice}')";
```

Is it the case?
If no, please share any errors you get.

Comment: i just forgot to put it in here when i was typing, but it wasn't the problem, with the codes i left, it doesn't insert the 2 select items in the drop down into the database.

Comment: I agree with Al3x_F4nt0m, you need to `var_dump` `$_POST['pack_choice']` and `$pack_choice` and `$qry` and check what goes wrong or share it here. Also you can do `var_dump(mysql_error())` right after `mysql_query()` to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pack_choice = implode(", ",$_POST['pack_choice']);
print_r($pack_choice); // HAVE YOU TRIED TO PRINT OUT //
$qry = "Insert INTO tbl_packages (pack_choice) VALUES ('{$pack_choice}');
$result_set = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: but printing out just prints out the selected values on the website, it doesn't really insert unless you do the query right?